An alternative to sysfs (/sys/class/gpio) for controlling GPIO
I have used GPIO sysfs-based approach to control CPU gpio pins, But the below functionality was deprecated from latest kernel version. what is the alternative to /sys/class/gpio for controlling GPIO from user-space?
echo 288 > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio288/direction
echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio288/value


The libgpiod-utils package has some utilities that use the GPIO chardev interface.
